# Efficient algorithm / recursive function to nest items from a list

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, nested

I'm currently implementing my own commenting system. Unfortunately Disqus or any other comment platform doesn't meet my requirements.

I use NodeJS and MongoDB as backend. I need to run basically two queries on my database:

- Get all comments by a topic/slug
- Get all comments by a user

One can comment to an topic or reply to a comment.

> Hey, cool post # top lvl comment
>
> > Thanks!        # reply to comment
> >
> > > Foo Bar!     # reply to reply
> > >
> > > > and so on...

So my database schema looks like

```
{
    id: ObjectId,
    text: string,
    author: { id: ObjectId, name: string },
    parent: nullable ObjectId,
    slug: string/number/whatever
}
```

If `parent` is null it's a top level comment, otherwise it's a reply.

Pretty easy so far, right? The problem I do have now is displaying comments below posts. When there would be only top level comments it would be easy. Just get all comments for one specific slug, sort them by date/rating/... and compile them with my HTML View Engine.

But there are in fact replies and I'm just stuck at the point where I need to organize my structure. I want to nest replies into comments within my list

Original list (simplified)

```
[
  { id: 1, text: 'foo', parent: null },
  { id: 2, text: 'bar', parent: 1 },
  // ...
]
```

Expected Output

```
[
  { id: 1, text: 'foo', replies: [
    { id: 2, text: 'bar' },
  ] },
]
```

I've tried creating my expected output with a recursive function which got very weird tho. Unless that it wouldn't be very efficient. So since I'm really getting frustrated and kinda feeling stupid not solving this problem I've decided to ask for your help SO.

The actual problem I want to solve: How do I render my comments, that they are properly nested etc.
The question I'm going to ask: How do I organize my flat structure in an efficient way to solve the above described problem?

Comment: can we not have another field called `level` that would indicate the depth ? In your example , `level = 0` for parent where as `level = 1` for comment whose id = 2 and so on? If there are multiple comments at the same `level` may be arrange per date/timestamp?

Comment: @SKY that'd be possible. I'm just not sure how it would solve my problem exactly :|

Comment: I would imagine the following way: `Hey, cool post # top lvl comment` would be a parent and thus `level = 0` , `Thanks!        # reply to comment` would be reply and `level = 1` , `Foo Bar!     # reply to reply` would have `level = 2`. I would repeat the same for all the parent comments (each parent comment would have `level = 0`) and would have its own thread of replies

Comment: @SKY could you post this with a real example as answer? I'm still having trouble getting my expected output with your logic. Or at least a way how to create my HTML with it.

Comment: @Brettetete - Would you ever a case where foo is bar's parent and bar is also foo's parent?  This may create an infinite loop if we aren't careful.

Comment: @Will I can't imagine a scenario where this could happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach with linear complexity:

```js
var comments = [{
  id: 3,
  text: 'second',
  parent: 1
}, {
  id: 1,
  text: 'root',
  parent: null
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: 'first',
  parent: 1
}, {
  id: 5,
  text: 'another first',
  parent: 4
}, {
  id: 4,
  text: 'another root',
  parent: null
}];

var nodes = {};

//insert artificial root node
nodes[-1] = {
  text: 'Fake root',
  replies: []
};

//index nodes by their id
comments.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.parent == null) {
    item.parent = -1;
  }
  nodes[item.id] = item;
  item.replies = [];
});

//put items into parent replies
comments.forEach(function(item) {
  var parent = nodes[item.parent];
  parent.replies.push(item);
});

//root node replies are top level comments
console.log(nodes[-1].replies);
```

Comment: You made my day.. even tho I could facepalm pretty much, your solution is pretty straight forward and obvious actually.